# Flutter: json_serializable ignore nullable fields instead of throwing an error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, json-serializable

Suppose there are two models **User** and **City**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    City? city;
    List<Map<String, City>>? listMapCity;

}

@JsonSerializable()
class City {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

Now suppose during API call, we've got a user model but in the city object model, we only get **id** not **name**. Something like this

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Matthew",
    "city": {
        "id": 12
    }
}
```

But due to the default nature of json_serializable and json_annotation.
This JSON is not mapped to the User model, during mapping, it throws the exception.
*type Null is not a subtype of type String. (because here **name** key is missing in city object)*

But as we already declared in the User object that City is optional, I wanted that it should parse the User JSON with **city** and **listMapCity** to be null.

Any help or solution would be really appreciated, Thank you

Comment: What Dart version are you using? If you are using Dart 2.12+, then you should mark the `name` field in City object as nullable - `String? name`.

Comment: I'm using Dart 2.13 but I don't want the name to be optional if the city object is coming then the id and name both should present.

Comment: Currently in iOS, I'm using this library https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox, this work just like I explained.

Comment: What do you want to do if only id is present and name is not there ?

Comment: Well, a User model should be created with the city as null.

Comment: Currently json_serializable throws the error, is there any way to just map the null instead of throws an error?

Comment: If you mark the field as nullable with String? name you get the result you want, if you don't you would get an error anyway because you assign null to a non nullable field

Answer (score 15):

You need to set the includeIfNull flag to false to have the autogenerated code handle nulls correctly.

```
@JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: false)
```

The property should be declared with a ? as per your example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a default constructor on your JsonSerializable `User` class. Then, if `name` should be nullable, declare it with a nullable `String? name;`

Here's the updated User class.

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  City? city;
  List<Map<String, City>>? listMapCity;

  User({required this.id, required this.name, this.city, this.listMapCity});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class City {
  int id;
  String name;
  City({required this.id, required this.name});
}
```